# Android. Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android

I'm learning the Udacity course of Developing Android Apps. While going through the instructions I came across this error. I would appreciate any help that would help me solve it.

I may have the same errors as other users however the code that's causing it might be different. Thanks for your patience

I have attached the logcat.
<------------------->

> 06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.android.sunshine.app/com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error
>   inflating class fragment 06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2329)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:147) 06-06
>   22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 06-06
>   22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 06-06 22:31:47.223:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 06-06
>   22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 06-06 22:31:47.223:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 06-06 22:31:47.223:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693) 06-06
>   22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358): Caused by:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error
>   inflating class fragment 06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 06-06
>   22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 06-06
>   22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 06-06
>   22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):    at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933) 06-06
>   22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  ... 10 more 06-06
>   22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358): Caused by:
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException 06-06 22:31:47.223:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418) 06-06
>   22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):    at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252) 06-06
>   22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):    at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215) 06-06
>   22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):    at
>   com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivityFragment.onCreateView(MainActivityFragment.java:98)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:924)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1116)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1218)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2170)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:300)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:838)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:34)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:826)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
>   06-06 22:31:47.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28358):  ... 19 more

<------------------------->

fagment_main.xml is

```
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"      
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingLeft="2dp"
     android:paddingRight="0dp"
     android:paddingTop="0dp"
     android:paddingBottom="0dp" tools:context=".MainActivityFragment"
    android:id="@+id/h">

         <ListView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:id = "@+id/listview_forecast"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is "NetworkOnMainThreadException".  You're trying to execute network requests on the main thread. You should make network requests only in background threads.

Comment: That's an error also however how should that effect  => android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment.

I'm not sure if it does as I'm new to android.

Comment: @Sidd, It's possible for one error to cause another. The "NetworkOnMainThreadException" is the underlying error, and is the one you should focus on.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try fixing that error! :D

Comment: Most of the people following the udacity tutorial are early beginners, perhaps you could be more specific with your answer?